# $.get seems to fail in IE 7,8 &9

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, get

For some reason, all IE browsers are not executing $get correctly like in other browsers, in other browsers it makes the call and goes throught the conditional statemente I have within the function (data). Anyone see what might be going wrong? Thanks! No error occurs it just doesn't go through it.

HTML

```
 <a href="layer_register.html" class="game-reg-button"> </a>
```

JQUERY

```
 $(document).on('click', '.game-reg-button', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var href = $(this).attr('href');
            emailaddress = $('#game-email').val();

var getstate ="";
var data;

     $.get('promo_getstate.php', {
            email: emailaddress,
            country: 'DE',
            lang: lang,
            source: '1304_Spring_dly'
        }, function (data) {

            getstate = data;


        if( !isValidEmailAddress( emailaddress ) ) {
          $('p.start.error').fadeIn(300); 

.....................................................



}); /*end .GET */
    });
```

Comment: Does your server receive the request?

Comment: what's the format of the `data` ? Is the response header giving the correct type ?

Comment: the data format is a simple response eg. response=1

Comment: @Jack it works on other browsers, I don't think the call is even going through to the php.

Comment: @dystroy If it likes to cache, shouldn't it at least run the success function? :)

Answer (score 0):

IE is famous for caching. Make sure that you are not receiving a cached result.

Append a unique timestamp at the end of your url and it will not be a cached result then. you can use jQuery [`now`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.now/) function.

```
 $.get('promo_getstate.php?'+$.now)(, {
    // your code goes here
 });
```

Comment: that didn't work :( just doesn't seem to make the call at all

Comment: use firebug to see what happens

Comment: In the IE console, it doesn't show any error, it doesnt seem to make the call to the php like it does in other browsers.